# Solving absolute value inequalities.

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove: If $z,\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z|<1, |\alpha|<1$ then $\dfrac{|z|^2+|\alpha|^2}{1+|\alpha z|^2}<1$

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people are much more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, your post is not currently phrased as a question, simply a statement, so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: Thanks Zev! Next time, I'll follow all your advice. :D

Comment: Great! Hope you enjoy using the site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, $|\alpha|^2+|z|^2-|\alpha z|^2=|\alpha|^2+|z|^2-|\alpha|^2|z|^2-1+1=1-(1-|\alpha|^2)(1-|z|^2)$. Now, Since $|\alpha|\lt 1$ and $|z|\lt 1\implies (1-|\alpha|^2)(1-|z|^2)\gt 0\implies 1-(1-|\alpha|^2)(1-|z|^2)\lt 1$ $$\implies |\alpha|^2+|z|^2-|\alpha z|^2\lt 1$$ $$\implies |\alpha|^2+|z|^2\lt|\alpha z|^2 + 1$$ $$\implies \frac{|\alpha|^2+|z|^2}{|\alpha z|^2 + 1}\lt 1$$ inequality remain unchanged on division as $|\alpha z|^2 + 1\gt 0$

Answer (score 2):

Because $0\leq |z|<1$ and $0\leq |\alpha|<1$, we have that $|z|^2<1$ and $|\alpha|^2<1$. Thus 
$$|z|^2-1<0\qquad\text{ and }\qquad |\alpha|^2-1<0,$$
so that 
$$0<(|\alpha|^2-1)(|z|^2-1).$$
Multiplying out the right side,
$$0<|\alpha|^2|z|^2-|\alpha|^2-|z|^2+1$$
and of course $|\alpha|^2|z|^2=|\alpha z|^2$, so that
$$|z|^2+|\alpha|^2<1+|\alpha z|^2.$$
Because $1+|\alpha z|$ is always a positive real number, we can divide both sides of the inequality by it to obtain
$$\frac{|z|^2+|\alpha|^2}{1+|\alpha z|^2}<1.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{|z|^2+|\alpha|^2}{1+|\alpha z|^2}<1$

iff $|z|^2+|\alpha|^2 < 1+|\alpha z|^2$ as both expressions are > 0

iff $(1-|z|^2)(1-|\alpha|^2)<0$

$(1-|z|^2)<0\ if\ |z|^2,1\ if\ |z|<1 $